# Parameters model estimation

Tags: optimization, models, estimation

I have this data (t, TR and h) and need to estimate the parameters (a, b, c, d and e) for this model: h = (a*log(TR)+b)*(c*(t^d)-e)*41.59

```
t <- c(120,60,50,40,30,20,10,180,120,60,50,40,30,20,10,120,60,50,40,30,20,10,120,60,50,40,30,20,10)
TR <- c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,20,20,20,20,20,20,20)
h <- c(49.4,41.6,39.1,36.2,31.9,25.1,15.9,80.2,70.3,55.2,51.6,47.3,41.7,33.2,22.1,84.2,64.1,59.9,54.6,48.1,38.6,26.2,97.5,72.8,67.9,61.6,54.3,43.7,30.1)

bell <- nls(h ~ ((a1*log(TR)+a2)*(a3*(t^b)-a4)*41.59), start = list(a=0.6, 
b2=0.3, c=0.4, d=0.30, e=0.4))
```

I tried the "nls" and the "nls2" process but these didn't work because of this: 
Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates

So,I founded a possible solution following this procedure (I think it's a Linearly Constrained Optimization): 
Solve this system of equations

```
U1 <- log(TR)*(c1*t^d1-e1)*41.59
U2 <- (c1*t^d1-e1)*41.59
U3 <- t^d1*(a1*log(TR)+b1)*41.59
U4 <- c1*t^d1*log(t)*((a1*log(TR))+b1)*41.59
U5 <- -(a1*log(TR)+b1)*41.59
```

From the initial values assumed for the parameters of the model,
successively the system of linear equations, in order to obtain values of the deviations each time nearest zero.

ΣZ = (a1-a) ΣU1,i + (b1-b) ΣU2,i + (c1-c) ΣU3,1 + (d1-d) ΣU4,i + (e1-e) ΣU5,i

For each iteration, the values of the parameters assume those obtained in
previous iteration, plus the deviations...

How could I do this in R?

I'm sorry cause I'm a R beginner and I don't speak english very well.
Many thanks for any help you can give me.

Comment: Is that particular parameterization important?  If not then note that the objective could be written as `A * log(TR) + B * t^b + C * log(TR) * t^b + D` which is linear in all parameters except `b` so can be solved using the plinear algorithm: `nls(h ~ cbind(log(TR), t^b, log(TR) * t^b, 1), start = list(b = 1), algorithm = "plinear")`